# Dependent predictors with converse effects on the target

Tags: predictive-models, cart, predictor

I am trying to create a predictive model for marketing in the natural gas field. The model is supposed to guess how probable it is to make a contract in that particular building given many internal and sociodemographic information. For sake of simplicity I tend to use decision trees. The target is a binary variable "contact won".

Number of existing customers in the building have a strong effect on the target variable, as expected. If there are already some customers there, their neighbors are likelier to make a contract as well. I also expect that the number of problem tickets should have a negative effect. So I added the input variable **ticket rate** *= # of problem tickets / # of customers*.

The problem is, if there is no customers in the building, it is missing. So my model infer that the probability of a contract is high if the ticket rate is not missing. If I ignore the observations with the missing values, then I have too few observations. What would be the best strategy here?

Comment: you can first null fill 'ticket rate'; the most naive way would be to null fill with average/median of existing ticket rates